# Google play services sdk: Requesting for offline access during auth

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-play-services, google-authentication

Is there a way to request for offline access using the Google play services sdk on android? I know that the [raw HTTP api](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization) has an option to do this by requesting for a refresh token, but couldn't find a way to do it via the new [Google Play services sdk](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html).

The new sdk gives the app an access token using the `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()` method, but the access token expires every hour. I could make the raw http request and have the user sign in from a web view or the browser, but would prefer a way to do it natively using the sdk, since that is a much better experience for the user.

Answer (score 1):

Searching the Google docs near and far, it does look like that this is possible. Google calls this "Cross-client Identity" under its ["Hybrid Apps"](https://developers.google.com/accounts/cookbook/platforms/Hybrid) category.

You can apparently massage the string for the scope parameter you pass into `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(...)` method to coax it into returning an "Authorization Code" rather than an OAuth2 Token. (For the difference between these, I've found [this chart](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#installed) helpful.)

The details are [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth), specifically the last section titled ["Android app obtains offline access for Web back-end"](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth#offlineAccess).

It seems you'll need to pass in the following as "scope" string to getToken:

```
oauth2:server:client_id:<your_server_client_id>:api_scope:<scope_url_1> <scope_url_2> ...
```

The doc then claims this:

> In this case, GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() will first require that the
>   user has authorized this Project for access to the two scopes.
>   Assuming this is OK, it will return, not an OAuth token, but a
>   short-lived authorization code, which can be exchanged for an access
>   token and a refresh token.

Disclaimer: I've not tried this myself yet; our Android developer will shortly. Please report if this is working for you.